# Ajax call will not refresh inner html with php function that makes the html - help?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I have the following code generating content on my site:

```
<div class="content" id="links">
    <?php displayTitle("Links"); ?>
    <?php displayContent("Links", $isLoggedIn); ?>
</div>
```

The content has a button that calls a Javascript function 'addLink()' to edit itself.  Here is the Javascript with an Ajax call to change the content:

```
function addLink(){
    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
    else{
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
            alert(ajaxRequest.readyState);
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('links');
            ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = "<?php displayTitle('Links'); ?><?php displayContent('Links', $isLoggedIn); ?>"
        } 
    }

    var imgURL = document.getElementById('links_img').value;
    var linkURL = document.getElementById('links_link').value;
    var queryString = "?imgURL=" + imgURL + "&linkURL=" + linkURL;
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "addLink.php" + queryString, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null);
}
```

'addLink.php' adds things to a table, theoretically allowing the content function 'displayContent()' to show the new entries in the table ('displayContent()' queries a table).

The PHP call works fine, but I have to refresh the page to see the changes.
Is there some problem with how I am doing this?  Possibly because there are already PHP calls in the inner HTML when the page is loaded in the first place?

Any help is appreciated, I'm a bit of a beginner with Ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        alert(ajaxRequest.readyState);
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
        var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('links');
        ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
    } 
}
```

Sorry a little correction.  You are attempting to access the pre-ajax php scripts inside ajax callback function.  That's not how it works.  You want the data that is retrived after-ajax call.  Ajax retrives the output from the GET request, and store in `ajaxRequest.responseText`.  Try replacing that and then see what you get.

In your addLink.php you should add the link and then echo out the data that you wish to display as the responseText.  What had happened is that you inject the data VIA addLink but you never actually display it on the client side VIA ajax correctly.  However, when you refresh the page, the script retrives what has been injected and display it accordingly.

Comment: glad i can help brother.  once you get a hang of it, its like woah this is fun =)